# How to Summarise And Group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

New to R, and trying to create some summaries of data.

```
test_data <- tibble(x=1:10,y=11:20, room=c("a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"), colour=c("red","blue","green","black","red","red","blue","green","black","red"))
summary_data <- test_data %>%
  filter(room != "NA") %>%
  group_by(room) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum(complete.cases(.)))) %>%
  rename_all(~paste0("risk_",colnames(summary_data)))
```

Gives:

```
> summary_data
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  risk_room risk_x risk_y risk_colour
  <chr>      <int>  <int>       <int>
1 a              5      5           5
2 b              5      5           5
```

Which is not at all what I want! What I'm trying for is :

[image]

Or

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using janitor and tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)
test_data <- tibble(x=1:10,y=11:20, room=c("a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"), colour=c("red","blue","green","black","red","red","blue","green","black","red"))

test_data %>%
    group_by(room, colour) %>%
    tally() %>% 
    spread(colour, n) %>%
    adorn_totals("col", name = "Count") %>%
    adorn_totals("row",name = "Total")
```

Comment: Thanks for the sharp answer. I checked out janitor a bit more. And found out how to add the percentages in too.
  
  adorn_percentages(denominator = "col") %>% 
  adorn_pct_formatting(digits = 0) %>% 
  adorn_ns(position = "front")